# What does it mean that the tag synonym requires 5 score?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

I made the tag [shia-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-islam) on the main Islam site, but when I tried to create a tag-synonym it shows me this error:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

What does this mean?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216067/221866 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/221866

Comment: @BleedingFingers thanks but one link has no answer and another is too long to read. can you post a short and useful answer to how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Feeling lazy to dive into this right now ;). If somebody doesn't come by I'll see into it and try to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your tag sore in the [tags tab of your profile](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/67/ahmadi?tab=tags).  For example, this is a screenshot from my own profile:

[image]

The first number (e.g.the one I have circled) is the tag score: I have a tag score of 9 on [finance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) and [christianity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity), and a tag score of 7 on [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) and [mythology](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology).  This score is based on the [total votes on any *non-wiki answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92699/132874) you have contributed; votes on questions, or community wiki posts, are not counted.

So you *should* be able to create a tag synonym using the [shiism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiism) tag as a master (i.e. creating the synonym from the [shiism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiism) page), since you have more than enough tag points for that.  But using a newly-created [shia-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-islam) as a master won't work until you have enough posts under that tag to accumulate points.

Comment: Although it might be sort of edit abuse but if OP simply changes any of the question in whose answer (s)he has 5>= votes then technical (s)he will be able to make the synonym.

Comment: I could not find the tag shia-islam in my tags at all!